# Capture Key Presses In Many GKState Classes

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using SpriteKit in Objective C for Mac OS. I'm a noob when it comes to working with NSNotification, but I used the following method in another app I was working on, but it's now not working. Perhaps there's a better method, but I want to be able to capture key presses based on what state the app is in.

#### The Main Issue

The state begins in `GameBeginState`. Once the spacebar is pressed, it moves into `GamePlayState`. If I press any other keys, it shows that it's using the `keyPressed:` method from `GameBeginState` as opposed to the `keyPressed` method in `GamePlayState`. Any ideas why? I can't figure this out for the life of me.

#### Details

I created a custom view called `CustomNotificationHandler` and set my main `SKView` in the project.

[image]

Here's the code for `CustomNotificationHandler`:

#### CustomNotificationHandler

```
#import "CustomNotificationHandler.h"

@implementation CustomNotificationHandler:SKView {
    // Add instance variables here

}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // Allocate and initialize your instance variables here

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:@{@"keyCode" : @(theEvent.keyCode)}];
}

@end
```

In my main class `GameScene` I have a `GKStateMachine` set up that initializes 3 states. The classes for the states are below:

#### GamePlayState.m

```
#import "GameReadyState.h"
#import "GamePlayState.h"

@interface GameReadyState()

@property (weak) GameScene *scene;

@end

@implementation GameReadyState

-(instancetype) initWithScene:(GameScene*)scene {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.scene = scene;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyPressed:) name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) didEnterWithPreviousState:(GKState *)previousState {

}

-(void) willExitWithNextState:(GKState *)nextState {

}

-(BOOL) isValidNextState:(Class)stateClass {
    return stateClass == [GamePlayState class];
}

-(void)keyPressed:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber *keyCodeObject = notification.userInfo[@"keyCode"];
    NSInteger keyCode = keyCodeObject.integerValue;
    NSLog(@"GAME READY key = %ld", (long)keyCode);
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 49:
            [self.stateMachine enterState:[GamePlayState class]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
@end
```

Here's the 2nd state...pretty much the same as the 1st:

#### GamePlayState

```
    #import "GamePlayState.h"
#import "GamePauseState.h"

@interface GamePlayState()

@property (weak) GameScene *scene;

@end

@implementation GamePlayState

-(instancetype) initWithScene:(GameScene*)scene {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.scene = scene;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyPressed:) name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) didEnterWithPreviousState:(GKState *)previousState {
    [_scene setPaused:NO];
}
-(BOOL) isValidNextState:(Class)stateClass {
    return stateClass == [GamePauseState class];
}

-(void) updateWithDeltaTime:(NSTimeInterval)seconds {
    [_scene.sequence moveLeft];
}

-(void)keyPressed:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber *keyCodeObject = notification.userInfo[@"keyCode"];
    NSInteger keyCode = keyCodeObject.integerValue;
    NSLog(@"GAME PLAY key = %ld", (long)keyCode);
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 53:
            [self.stateMachine enterState:[GamePauseState class]];
            [_scene setPaused:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Que!?  Why do you need to use NSNotification to see which key is down?

Comment: If I use the keydown method in my scene, it very quickly gets very messy because of the various states I have to account for. What would you suggest instead?